# Entries of a matrix raised to any real power

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A=(a_{ij})$ is an $n\times n$ real matrix and define $T(A)=\max\{|a_{ij}|\}$, where the maximum is taken over $1\leq i,j \leq n$.

I know how to show that $T(AB)\leq nT(A)T(B)$ for all $A$ and $B$.

Show that $T(A^{r})\leq n^{r-1}(T(A))^{r}$ for all $A$ and all $r\geq 1, r\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How do you define real power of a matrix?

Comment: I am also not sure about that. I was just assuming that for a rational number, $A^{p/q}$ is some matrix $B$ such that $B^{q}=A^{p}$. And for a real number, $r$, $A^{r}$ can be a limit of $A$ raised to the power of rational numbers approaching $r$. Any thoughts?

Comment: @neelp: in general $B$ is neither guaranteed to exist nor be unique.

Comment: That is true. The question must have meant for $r$ to be a positive integer. Right?

Comment: Then the simplest recursion one can think of seems to yield the proof, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. Then the problem is easy.

Comment: @neelp You could write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assume r is a positive integer,

$$T(A^r)=T(AA^{r-1})\leq nT(A)T(A^{r-1})\leq\cdots\leq n^{r-2}\,(T(A))^{r-2}\,T(A^2)\leq n^{r-1}\,(T(A))^r$$
where we used $T(AB)\leq n\,T(A)\,T(B)$ recursively.